# Not sure how to read through the line and find the desired word

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I need to do is this:

Write a program that categorizes each mail message by which day of the week the commit was done. To do this look for lines that start with “From”, then look for the third word and keep a running count of each of the days of the week. At the end of the program print out the contents of your dictionary (order does not matter).

I've gotten the basics down reading into the file searching, but I can't figure out how I would have python search through the line to find the day of the week and then add to the count. The method I tried returns an error.

I'm using Repl.it to run python and it is v3 of it. if you need to view the txt file here it is http://www.pythonlearn.com/code3/mbox.txt

```py
sat = 0
sun = 0
mon = 0
tue = 0
wed = 0
thur = 0
fri = 0

try:
  relettter = open('mbox.txt', 'r')
  rd = relettter.readlines()

  for line in rd:
            # line that is being read
            lnLen = len(line)
            srch = line.startswith("From ")

            # only parse the confidence value if there is a match
            if srch != -1:
                dayOfWeek = '' #The value 

                if 'Sat' in srch:
                  sat += 1
                elif dayOfWeek == 'Sun':
                  sun += 1
                elif dayOfWeek == 'Mon':
                  mon += 1
                elif dayOfWeek == 'Tue':
                  tue += 1
                elif dayOfWeek == 'Wed':
                  wed += 1
                elif dayOfWeek == 'Thu':
                  thur += 1
                elif dayOfWeek == 'Fri':
                  fri += 1


  print("Days of the days of the week")
  print("Saturday: ", sat)
  print("Sunday: ", sun)



except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I also would not mind a little help with the if statement, I have a tendency to do that and I would like to know a better method

The results should print out the number of times each day of the week was mentioned within the file where they meet the desired conditions. For example Saturday : 23

Comment: `startswith` returns a `bool`, which is only 0 or 1, never -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right collection to simplify your logic (that's the most important advice I ever got about programming). In this case, an ordinary dict is a reasonable choice and it helps a lot:

```
counts = {}

with open('mbox.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('From '):
            words = line.split()
            day = words[2]
            if day in counts:
                counts[day] += 1
            else:
                counts[day] = 1
```

But an even better choice would be a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

with open('mbox.txt') as fh:
    counts = Counter(line.split()[2] for line in fh if line.startswith('From '))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well and answered both of my questions!

Answer (score 1):

```
fname=input('Enter the file name: ') 
if len(fname)<1:
    fname='mbox.txt'
hand=open(fname)
di=dict()
for line in hand:
    words=line.rstrip().split()
    if len(words)<3 or words[0] != 'From':
        continue
    di[words[2]]=di.get(words[2],0)+1
print(di)
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the `for line in rd` loop into this:

```py
for line in rd:
# only check line if it starts with From
    if line.startswith("From "):
        # find the day
        if 'Sat' in line:
                sat += 1
            elif 'Sun' in line:
                sun += 1
            elif 'Mon' in line:
                mon += 1
            elif 'Tue' in line:
                tue += 1
            elif 'Wed' in line:
                wed += 1
            elif 'Thu' in line:
                thur += 1
            elif 'Fri' in line:
                fri += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iread=input('enter the file name: ')
fread=open(iread)

oxford=dict()
for line in fread:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        nline=line.rstrip().split()
        word=nline[2]
        oxford[word]=oxford.get(word,0)+1
print(oxford)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a brief explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.